# Can't enter the NumberFormatException

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

I was trying to write a program that prompts the user to read two integers and displays their sum and my program should prompt the user to read the number again if the input is incorrect. That's what I came up with:

```
import java.util.*;
public class NumFormatException {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 2 integers: ");
        int num1=0;
        int num2=0;


            boolean isValid = false;

            while (!isValid)  {
            try
            {
                num1=input.nextInt();
                num2=input.nextInt();
                isValid=true;
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException ex)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
            }
        }
            System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + (num1 + num2));
    }

}
```

My main goal is to put the user in a situation to **re-enter an integer** if the input is **incorrect**. When I enter two integers, operation work well but my problem is with the exception: when I enter for example **a** instead of an integer, my program crashed.

Comment: Its `InputMismatchException` not `NumberFormatException`. Since you are not converting `string` to `int` here.

Comment: @Satya When I put InputMismatchException instead of numberFormatException the program print "Invalid Input" an infinite time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here. First, If a `nextXYZ` method of `Scanner` encounters a wrong input, it won't throw a `NumberFormatException` but an [`InputMismatchException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html). Second, if such an exception is thrown, the input token won't be consumed, so you need to consume it explicitly again:

```
try {
    num1=input.nextInt();
    num2=input.nextInt();
    isValid=true;
} catch (InputMismatchException ex) { // catch the right exception
    System.out.println("Invalid input");
    // consume the previous, erroneous, input token(s)
    input.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: I don't get it, sorry. "the input token won't be consumed, so you need to consume it explicitly again". Plz any more explanation

Comment: @Satya I'm new to java, I don't get the verb **consume**

Comment: [nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) @JohnyNassar

Comment: @Satya Ok I know that nexLine() is to read an input from keyboard but what input? The incorrect input???

Comment: If you pass a non-numeric string that fails `nextInt()`, that string will still remain as the input for the next `nextXYZ` call, as the scanner didn't successfully read it. This means the next `nextInt()` call will just try reading it again, and just fail, again. `nextLine()` reads it and just ignores it (since we don't want it anyway) so that the scanner can freely read the next (hopefully valid) input.